# Build project with libvpx x86 android fail with undefined reference error

Tags: android, c++, c, android-x86

I need to add to android project atom processor support. Config and build libvpx library  under x86 with parameters:

> ./configure --disable-examples --sdk-path = '/ Android / ndk' --enable-vp8 --target = x86-android-gcc --disable-postproc
>   
> make

build success and I get a static library libvpx.a
Add library to project:

> include $ (CLEAR_VARS) 
>   LOCAL_MODULE: = vpx 
>   LOCAL_SRC_FILES: = thirdparty / webm / libvpx / $ (TARGET_ARCH_ABI) / libvpx.a 
>   include $ (PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES: = stdc++ jpeg png vorbis vorbisfile vorbisenc theora theoradec libwebp vpx

but during the assembly of the project was getting errors :

> jni/thirdparty/webm/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a (vp8_dx_iface.co) (. text +0 x568): error: undefined reference to '__vsnprintf_chk' 
>   jni/thirdparty/webm/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a (vp8_dx_iface.co) (. text +0 x596): error: undefined reference to '__longjmp_chk' 
>   jni/thirdparty/webm/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a (onyxd_if.co) (. text +0 x158): error: undefined reference to '__vsnprintf_chk' 
>   jni/thirdparty/webm/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a (onyxd_if.co) (. text +0 x186): error: undefined reference to '__longjmp_chk' 
>   jni/thirdparty/webm/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a (onyxd_if.co) (. text.unlikely +0 x23): error: undefined reference to '__assert_fail' 
>   jni/thirdparty/webm/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a (yv12extend.co): function vp8_yv12_extend_frame_borders_c: error: undefined reference to '__assert_fail' 
>   jni/thirdparty/webm/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a (yv12extend.co): function vp8_yv12_extend_frame_borders_c: error: undefined reference to '__assert_fail' 
>   jni/thirdparty/webm/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a (yv12extend.co): function vp8_yv12_extend_frame_borders_c: error: undefined reference to '__assert_fail' 
>   jni/thirdparty/webm/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a (decodframe.co) (. text +0 x198): error: undefined reference to '__vsnprintf_chk' 
>   jni/thirdparty/webm/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a (decodframe.co) (. text +0 x1c6): error: undefined reference to '__longjmp_chk' 
>   jni/thirdparty/webm/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a (boolhuff.co) (. text +0 x55): error: undefined reference to '__longjmp_chk' 
>   jni/thirdparty/webm/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a (onyx_if.co) (. text +0 xa08): error: undefined reference to '__vsnprintf_chk'

Does anyone know how to fix it? Build project under armeabi is successfully.
Trying to add flags APP_CPPFLAGS +=-std=gnu++11 and change the version of ndk

> NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION: = 4.8

other flags of the project:

> APP_STL: = gnustl_static 
>   APP_CPPFLAGS + =-frtti-fexceptions 
>   APP_CFLAGS + =-Wno-error = format-security 
>   APP_ABI: = armeabi x86

used in the construction of ndk android-ndk-r9d-linux-x86 (I tried to use android-ndk-r9d-linux-x86_64 - the same result), Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64, Eclipse 3.8.1

Answer (score 3):

For me adding `--extra-cflags="-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE"` covered `__longjmk_chk` and `__vsnprintf_chk`

And I wrote empty `__assert_fail` function : `extern "C" { void __assert_fail() {} }`